# MySQL - how can I do a join and order by the sum of votes?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have schema like this (just experimenting, so if you have improvement suggestions I am all ears):

```
mysql> describe contest_entries;
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type           | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| entry_id      | int(10)        | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| member_id     | int(10)        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| person_name   | varchar(10000) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date          | date           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| platform      | varchar(30)    | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| business_name | varchar(100)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| url           | varchar(200)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| business_desc | varchar(3000)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| guid          | varchar(50)    | YES  | UNI | NULL    |                |
+---------------+----------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
9 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> describe contest_votes;
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| vote_id          | int(10) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id          | int(10) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contest_entry_id | int(10) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| vote             | int(7)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I am trying to pull the data as a leaderboard, ordering the results by the most votes. How would I do that? I am able to do the left-join part, but the sum and the ordering part of the query is confusing me.

Thank you!

Comment: Since you don't know how to get a sum, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL is 10 Minutes.  As far as your schema is concerned, the person_name should probably not be in the contest_entries table.  You should be able to get it with the member_id field from another table.  Also, what is the purpose of the guid field in contest_entries?

Comment: @DanBracuk the guid is to avoid duplicate entries. I am experimenting not typing it to member_id for uniqueness so that I don't have to force people to register.

Comment: Would there be one row per vote in `contest_votes` or just one row per `contest_entry_id` or `user_id` where you increment the `vote` column?

Comment: @Eternal-Learner I am thinking one row per vote.

Comment: Then you dont need `vote` column. and you just need count of rows in `contest_votes` for a given `contest_entry_id`

Comment: @Eternal-Learner good point! Thank you! How would the query look like if I took out the vote column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT entry_id
FROM contest_entries
LEFT OUTER JOIN contest_votes ON entry_id = contest_entry_id
GROUP BY entry_id
ORDER BY SUM(vote) DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select e.entry_id, sum(v.vote) as votes
from contest_entries e
left join contest_votes v on e.entry_id = v.contest_entry_id 
group by e.member_id
order by votes desc
```